# Selenium POM - "this.driver" is null

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am learning about POM Selenium + Java. I want to refactor class for tests. Right now I have one class but I want divide code into two class: one class will be for initializing browser with adnotations @BeforeClass and @AferClass and second will be with just @Test.
When I refactor my code I get error java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "this.driver" is null . My code only works if I have @After, @Before and @Test in one class.

My code for refactor:

```
public class TC1LoginRegisterUser {
    WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        homePage.navigateToUrl();
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

My code after refactor:

```
public class BaseClass {

    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void teardown() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

```
public class TC1LoginRegisterUser extends BaseClass {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        homePage.navigateToUrl(); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Sure, this should work just fine, as long as your test class does indeed extend your base class. JUnit will run all the annotated methods. If it doesn't work for you, attach a debugger and see what gets executed when. Note that JUnit's default is to make a new instance of the test class for each test, so your `driver` field (and the before/after methods) should probably be `static`.

Comment: And note that `BeforeClass` and `Before` are different. Same for `After`. Read the javadoc on those classes for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your refactor work as expected, you should make method and `driver` variable `static` as far as `@BeforeClass` executes method when class instance has not been created yet, so non static entities are `null`.

```js
static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public static void setupAll() {
   driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
```

but I suggest to use `@Before` except `@BeforeClass` annotation in your Base class, that would allow you to make `driver` non-static.